# Is there a way to put the "Recent" list in the welcome page in its own column?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I noticed the change in VS Code (v1.77) Welcome page design, there is only one column now and thus less "Recent" items.

[image]

As I remember older page design, there was more "Recent" items visible. The screenshot taken from https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_57#_new-getting-started-experience
agrees with my memory.

[image]

Was this intentional change in recent VS Code upgrade? Is there any way to restore original two column design with more "Recent" items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug at least in the case that you've closed all the new-user-guidance stuff: [Incorrect layout of welcome page, when there are no suggestions #178831](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/178831). It should be fixed by this PR in the May 2023 Milestone: [Re-render recent list on welcome page to right column if no walkthroughs/featured extensions #181355](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/181355)

Also possibly historically related, from googling "`site:github.com/microsoft/vscode "welcome" "recent" OR "recents" move`", I found some other issue tickets:

- [Explore improving UX for Welcome Page #63152](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/63152)
- [add more entries to Open Recent / Recent #99547](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/99547)
- [Better utilization of the screen real estate in the welcome screen
  #128984](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/128984)